# How to automatically drop & create tables with Glassfish v3 & PostgreSQL 8.4?

Tags: java, postgresql, deployment, glassfish-3

I've got a simple web app that should store data into my postgreSQL database.
There's a class "Person" which is annotated as @Entity, there's a JDBC Connection Pool and a JDBC Resource.

When I try to deploy it by the command

```
asadmin deploy --name=miniejb --force=true --dropandcreatetables=true ~/workspace/miniejb/bin
```

I get error messages:

> Cannot drop tables for application miniejb. The expected DDL file miniejb_miniejb_dropDDL.jdbc is not available.
>
> Cannot create tables for application miniejb. The expected DDL file miniejb_miniejb_createDDL.jdbc is not available.

The Connection Pool is pingable via the glassfish administration interface. The database is running, everything is fine. I just don't get where the error messages are coming from. I think it is a configuration issue, but I don't know what to change. I tried everything imaginable with the connection pool properties.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

GlassFish is complaining about not being able to find the *drop jdbc ddl file* and the *the create jdbc ddl file* (that must be specified in your `persistence.xml`).

I don't have much experience with this feature so I'm not sure where those files are supposed to be located but I suggest to check:

- [Glassfish and Automatic Table Generation](http://blogs.oracle.com/java2dbInGlassFish/entry/automatic_table_generation_feature_in)
- [Generation Options](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/819-3659/gbwmk?a=view)

Comment: Unfortunately, the links have now expired. Seems Oracle doesn’t believe in **Cool URLs don’t change** :(

Answer (score 0):

I also got hit by this on GlassFish 3.1.

Probably this bug: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-12621

Try restarting the server.